# How to make background of an animated gif transparent using PHP?

Tags: php, transparency, gif, animated-gif

I use this library https://github.com/lunakid/AnimGif to compose a animated GIF from single frames. But when I have an alpha channel the result GIF will always have a black or another coloured background.

I tried all GIF libraries for PHP I found. Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Best,
intxcc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably are using GIFs with transparent background as INPUT frames.
Use PNGs (!) with a transparent background as INPUT frames and most php gif libraries should generate a GIF with transparent background.

Comment: I'm already using a transparent PNG as the input. So I think this answer is incorrect.

Comment: Which library are you using?